# Survey package/DHS data: nonsensical standard errors

Tags: spatial, survey

I'm trying to use the survey package to perform small area estimation for household cattle ownership (variable hv246a) in the Malawi 2010 DHS dataset. I'm running into issues with the svyby function.

The parent DHS dataset is the household dataset (MWHR61FL.DTA). The cluster variable is hv021, household weight (*1,000,000) is hv005, sampling stratum is hv021, and the cattle variable is hv246a.

My code is:

```
dhs.des<-svydesign(id=data$hv021, weights=data$hv005/1000000, strata=data$v022, data=data)
cattle<-svyby(~hv246a, ~hv021, dhs.des, svymean)
```

There are 849 clusters (hv021) and 23,020 households (units) in this dataset.

The standard errors for the output are:

```
> summary(cattle$se)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 4.674e-17 3.556e-17 1.082e-15
```

The weighted estimates (cattle$cattle) look fine, but these standard errors look nonsensical to me.

Thanks,
Julianne

Comment: hi, i bet that `/1000000` is the problem.  maybe work through the malawi example at http://asdfree.com/demographic-and-health-surveys-dhs.html  ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll look through this! I'm pretty sure the weights are right (from https://www.dhsprogram.com/pubs/pdf/DHSG4/Recode6_DHS_22March2013_DHSG4.pdf): "Sample weight is an 8 digit variable with 6 implied decimal places. To use the sample weight divide it by 1000000 before applying the weighting factor." Also, if I don't divide by 1000000 then the means don't look right.